# Optaplanner + Spring Boot. Is it possible to inject bean in ConstraintProvider implementation class?

Tags: optaplanner

I have an application with Optaplanner + Spring Boot, which solves VRP problem. One of the needs for solving this problem is to know the distances between two points. I do this through a separate class that makes the http request. I tried to inject a bean of this class through the @Autowired annotation, but the bean is not injected. Therefore, the question is whether it is possible to inject bean into the ConstrainProvider, since I don’t want to drag this dependency into the DAO layer

Comment: Good question. This is a common request. Related to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2408 (vote for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConstraintProvider` is not even instantiated as a bean in the Spring context, so you cannot inject anything into it.

Important to note, that making any HTTP requests from the constraints in the `ConstraintProvider` will kill the performance.

If possible, try incorporating the distance matrix into your domain model and initialize it before solving.